# Suspend and resume isn't working on an ASUS X54CBBK3

Tags: 12.04, laptop, suspend, asus

I am more or less a complete Linux noob, and using 12.04 for the first time. Everything works great, and I am very happy, but there is one exception: suspend won't resume. Every time I suspend my computer, (whether by clicking suspend or by closing the lid) it goes to a black screen (with the backlight on) but there is no way to wake it up.

I've tried doing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to see if the screen was off, but it didn't work. I tried keyboard, mouse and power button, but nothing works, and I have to shut down and restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[...]Remove the comment sign from the line `SAVE_VIDEO_PCI_STATE=true` in the file `/etc/default/acpi-support`. "

A comment found on [this thread.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742470)
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't find '/etc/default/acpi-support'

Comment: And what's a comment sign?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my Zareason Verix (ubuntu 12.04 with nvidia gts 250m)

Comment: Hashtag '#' is a comment sign. #this is a comment.

Comment: oh. And where is `/etc/default/acpi-support`

Comment: I found it and changed it, but I can't save the edit because I don't own the file. How can I not own the file? I'm the only user, the only person who has ever used the computer?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to change it, and I did and saved the new one. When I tested suspend, it went to the same black screen with the backlight on as before, but this time there was "checking battery status..." on the left top of the screen, and [ Ok ] on the right. It stayed there without doing anything, and there was no way to wake it up.

Comment: Did you try reboot before changing the file?

Comment: yeah, I've rebooted plenty of times since every time I test suspend, I have to reboot to get out of it

Comment: For some reason, my suspend now works again, and I did make the change that @Erro made. It just didn't start working until around 5 reboots.