# Cannot resume from suspend 12.04

Tags: 12.04, suspend

I suspend, I wake up. There is no network connectivity, there is no USB activity, there is no video output. The computer is turned on but nobody is home, just a black screen.

I have a 4 port KVM and a Geforce 9600 GSO.

- I have tested connecting to this box via ssh, it times out
- My keyboard doesn't respond when I try that session switch fix. I also tried a script that did the same thing essentially. Both failed
- I have tested editing `/etc/default/acpi-support` (`SAVE_VIDEO_PCI_STATE=true` did not work)
- I have tested the ACPI boot options.

(Result)

`pci=noacpi` doesn't work

`acpi=off` disables suspend so I don't even understand how that was a fix for someone.

I attempted to use a fix posted here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#Force_Pipe_A_Quirk
This broke x server so that it wouldn't run at all. I managed to disable it booting into recovery and editing the xorg.conf file with `sudo nano`. Booting normally it simply would freeze on the splash screen I couldn't get it to display what was going on so I had to restart.

I did find one fix for a laptop(which I don't have) that involved HDD power management stuff but I couldn't figure out how to do something like that for my desktop.

Couldn't find any help for this on irc, and my search results aren't pulling up anything new. Still haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: recommend merge with http://askubuntu.com/questions/177628/suspend-and-resume-isnt-working-on-an-asus-x54cbbk3

Comment: Sorry I forgot one, I also tried that.

Comment: Do you use disk encryption?

Comment: No encryption. I do have my installation spread between two HDDs. I have a PATA and SATA drive (160/320 GB drives in that order). I have my SWAP at the front of the PATA and root at the back of it. Then on the SATA I have my /usr and /home then an additional mount specifically for files that I wanted set aside. However none of that should have any effect (in my opinion at least, but I am a newbie so I don't know)

Comment: No solution, I will probably just give up on this. I will maybe get ahold of a SSD for my linux box and just hibernate... unless this gets fixed, must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

> Force Pipe A Quirk This problem typically exhibits itself on Intel 
>   graphics hardware (most particularly i855) by locking up the machine 
>   when closing the lid. The fix for this issue is to quirk your card to 
>   force enabling Pipe A. If you suspect you're having this bug, try 
>   setting this option in your xorg.conf:
>
> ```
>  Section "Device"
>      ..
>      Option "ForceEnablePipeA" "true" EndSection
> ```

Fore more reference visit the source of the above quote:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#Force_Pipe_A_Quirk

Comment: I have an nvidia graphics card and an AMD Athlon 64 x2 6000+ processor. Secondly, this is not a laptop with a lid, it is a desktop computer. So basically, no I haven't. Should I?

Comment: well yes. first of all it says TIPICALLY on intel graphics, not only on intel vga, and second when you close the lid of the laptop you put it on suspend, thus, more commonly on a laptop. Since you suspend your DESKTOP it is exactly the same as you would close the lid, so yes, you shoud, then again, this is just MY option, everyone is free to do what ever they want.

Comment: Alright, it just struck me as more of a x server related issue than a suspend/resume one, rather triggered by the suspend/resume. I'll give it a try in the morning. I'll edit the details if it doesn't work.

Comment: So this completely broke my boot cycle.... I don't think this fix was intended for me.

Comment: did you manage to get it back?

Comment: Yes, I had to boot into recovery and sudo nano to edit the line out.

Answer (score 0):

looks like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/217148/82136) is not much useful in your case.but its not bad to take a look anyway.
I have to say that Im upset from this problem myself (Ubuntu 11.10,Nvidia GeForce 310M)