# Ubuntu will suspend but won't wake up

Tags: 12.10, suspend, macbook-pro, wakeup

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an Apple MacBook Pro 9,1 Mid 2012 15inch non retina. Suspend suspends it but when I open the lid, it doesn't wake up. I tried pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 but nothing works. Only the keyboard backlight switches on. What's the issue?

Moreover, I'm using  the X org `nouveau` driver and not the official nVidia one. Please help. It is irritating to shut the laptop down every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 13.04 and above, sleep and wake up works perfectly once you install NVIDIA's drivers. They don't work on the `nouveau` drivers.

Comment: What if I have this issue when I have an NVIDIA driver?

Answer (score 2):

Preferably try to fix your Hibernation function if its not working too.
because in similar cases with "sleep problem",seems hibernate is more handy and workable solution.refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/180776/82136)

- Test **pci=noacpi** as a boot parameter
- take a look at **/etc/default/acpi-support** , probably it needs some changes
- and if you are lucky, this command can help you:

  sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/*

all in all,it looks like this kind of troubles is related to hardware thing (Graphic Driver incompatibility
or Power Manager) so why you don't try appropriate NVidia driver for your OS distribution?

Comment: Problem is I'm unable to install the nVidia driver http://askubuntu.com/questions/207578/do-nvidias-drivers-work-in-12-10

Please see my comments about a black screen in one of the answers

Comment: So.. guess its too late to answer! but after I read those comments,I think thats because of nVidia driver you installed.theres much differences between your hardwares but you can disable or change your graphic mode in boot-parameters.theres many documents describe it.change vga modes and find safest you can.I'm going to post some of them

Comment: I uninstalled the nvidia drivers after the black screen itself. This question still stands. Will try out your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live CD try using it and boot-repair tool.seems theres    nothing wrong with grub but it's good idea to change some boot    options. These are some useful options mentioned by canonical itself..

- **vga=xxx**

Set your framebuffer resolution to VESA mode xxx. Check here for a list of possible modes.

- **acpi=off OR noacpi**

This parameter disables the whole ACPI system. This may prove very useful, for example, if your computer does not support ACPI or if you think the ACPI implementation might cause some problems (for instance random reboots or system lockups).

- **acpi=force**

Activates the ACPI system even if your computer BIOS date is older than 2000. This parameter overrides acpi=off and can also be used with current hardware if the ACPI support is not activated despite apm=off.

- **pci=noacpi OR acpi=noirq**

These parameters disable the PCI IRQ routing

- **pci=acpi**

This parameter activates the PCI IRQ routing

- **acpi_irq_balance**

ACPI is allowed to use PIC interrupts to minimize the common use of IRQs.

- **acpi_irq_nobalance**

ACPI is not allowed to use PIC interrupts.

- **acpi=oldboot**

Deactivates the ACPI system almost completely; only the components required for the boot process will be used.

- **acpi=ht**

Deactivates the ACPI system almost completely; only the components required for hyper threading will be used.

- **noapic**

Disable the "Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (APIC)".

- **nolapic**

Disable the "local APIC".

- **apm=off OR noapm**

Disable the Advanced Power Management.

- **irqpoll**

Changes the way the kernel handles interrupt calls (set it to polling). Can be useful in case of hardware interrupt issues.

- **acpi.power_nocheck=1 OR acpi_osi=linux**

Disable the check of power state or changes the OS compatibility reported to the BIOS. Necessary on some broken BIOSes to make temperature/fan control work.

refer to this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions